# using ddply in R to flag max values

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
 
Gene           Sample        Mutation Count

    BRAF           ER5              WT     1
    BRAF           ES1              WT     1
    BRAF           ES2         p.V600E     4
    BRAF           ES2              WT     1
    BRAF           FRO         p.V600E     3
    BRAF           FRO              WT     1
    TP53           HMVII       p.G469V     1
    TP53           HMVII            WT     4
    TP53           hn15             WT     1
    TP53           HN5              WT     2
    TP53           HNS              WT     1
```

we are interested in  first flagging those duplicates from the Gene and Sample (not mutation), indicating which are duplicated and indicate which duplicate entry is the maximum and which is not the max (can have more that 2 duplicates) based on the count field (If they are equal we can call it 'max').

The second piece of information in a (separate column) is to capture the tallies of the data for each mutation, which would be the same for redundant entries. The corresponding output data would look like this:

```
    Gene           Sample       Mutation Count      Flag            Tally
    BRAF           ER5              WT     1        ok              WT
    BRAF           ES1              WT     1        ok              WT
    BRAF           ES2         p.V600E     4        dup, max        p.V600E(4),WT(1)
    BRAF           ES2              WT     1        dup, not-max    p.V600E(4),WT(1)
    BRAF           FRO         p.V600E     3        dup, max        p.V600E(3),WT(1)
    BRAF           FRO              WT     1        dup, not-max    p.V600E(3),WT(1)
    TP53           HMVII       p.G469V     1        dup, not-max    p.G469V(1),WT(4)
    TP53           HMVII            WT     4        dup, max        p.G469V(1),WT(4)
    TP53           hn15             WT     1        ok              WT
    TP53           HN5              WT     2        dup, max        WT(2),WT(1)
    TP53           HNS              WT     1        dup, not-max    WT(2),WT(1)
```

Any ideas how to best go about this? I'm thinking ddply would be best but not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Combination of `plyr` and `base::merge()`, I think. My result table looks different to yours, but I think it's right because the last two `Sample` entries are different HN5 and HNS?

```
g<-read.csv("g.csv")
require(plyr)

g.summarized<-ddply(g,
                    .(Gene,Sample),
                    summarise,
                    c=length(Mutation),
                    max=max(Count),
                    tally=paste0(paste0(Mutation,"(",Count,")"),collapse=","))
g.new<-merge(g,
             g.summarized,
             by=c("Gene","Sample"),all=TRUE)


getFlag<-function(Count,c,max){
  max<-ifelse(Count==max,"max","not-max")
  ok<-ifelse(c==1,"ok",paste0("dup, ",max))
  return(ok)
}

ddply(g.new,
      .(Gene,Sample,Mutation),
      summarise,
      Count=Count,
      Flag=getFlag(Count,c,max),
      Tally=tally)

   Gene Sample Mutation Count         Flag            Tally
1  BRAF    ER5       WT     1           ok            WT(1)
2  BRAF    ES1       WT     1           ok            WT(1)
3  BRAF    ES2  p.V600E     4     dup, max p.V600E(4),WT(1)
4  BRAF    ES2       WT     1 dup, not-max p.V600E(4),WT(1)
5  BRAF    FRO  p.V600E     3     dup, max p.V600E(3),WT(1)
6  BRAF    FRO       WT     1 dup, not-max p.V600E(3),WT(1)
7  TP53  HMVII  p.G469V     1 dup, not-max p.G469V(1),WT(4)
8  TP53  HMVII       WT     4     dup, max p.G469V(1),WT(4)
9  TP53   hn15       WT     1           ok            WT(1)
10 TP53    HN5       WT     2           ok            WT(2)
11 TP53    HNS       WT     1           ok            WT(1)
```

Comment: Thanks Troy, this is tremendously helpful!